# Using require('react-native') as this["require"]('react-native') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to write React Native code in ScalaJs and this brings multiple limitations, one of them is that ScalaJs generates requirements in the following form:

```
this.React = this["require"]("react-native");
```

When I run the app, I get import errors for the `react-native` and the `BatchedBridge` modules. If I change the line above to:

```
this.React = this.require("react-native");
```

Then it works!

I tried this in the `Hello World` app and saw the same results.

The diff I get between the 2 bundle files is:

```
< __d('AwesomeProject/index.ios',[],function(global, require, requireDynamic, requireLazy, module, exports) {  /**
---
> __d('AwesomeProject/index.ios',["react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native"],function(global, require, requireDynamic, requireLazy, module, exports) {  /**
943c943
< var React = this["require"]('react-native');
---
> var React = this.require('react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native');
```

After this diff, there are also tons of code added to the version that works (some imports done by the preprocessor?)

Is there a way to have the packager also work with the first line?

Comment: But those lines are functionally the same; what is the problem? From the first paragraph, it sounds like you are asking for off-site resources.

Comment: Even though these two lines are functionally the same, they behave differently once passed to the preprocessor. Try in the hello world example with `var React = this.require('react-native');`, it should work; try with `var React = this["require"]('react-native');`, it doesn't. I might be missing the obvious here.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the react-native JSX processor. Filed here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/465